# JPA AuditorAware not getting created for each user

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, audit

I have implemented auditing using JPA auditing. My code looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "auditorAware")
public class JpaConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Scope(value= ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public AuditorAware<String> auditorAware() {
        final String currentUser;
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if(null != authentication) {
            currentUser = authentication.getName();
        } else {
            currentUser = null;
        }
        return () -> Optional.ofNullable(currentUser);
    }
}
```

The issue I am facing is if I login with one user and perform some operation, it's working fine. But when I logout and login with another user, It's still using the last user only.

After debugging the code what I found is spring not creating bean of AuditorAware for each user. It's behaving like singleton bean. Even I specify the scope as prototype also, still it's behaving like singleton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `AuditorAware` is supposed to be a singleton. You should retrieve the current user, each time the `AuditAware.getCurrentAuditor` is called. Not just once.

Rewrite your code to something like this.

```
@Bean
public AuditorAware<String> auditorAware() {
    return () -> getCurrentAuthentication().map(Authentication::getName());
}

private Optional<Authentication> getCurrentAuthentication() {
  return Optional.ofNullable(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication());
}
```